# Highly divisible triangular number(ProjectEular)?

Tags: java

The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28. The first ten terms would be:

1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...

Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:

1: 1
 3: 1,3
 6: 1,2,3,6
10: 1,2,5,10
15: 1,3,5,15
21: 1,3,7,21
28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors.

What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

I did this in java with this code. I don't see any errors but it returns whatever value I give to count2. What is the reason?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(number());
}


public static boolean triangle(int number) {
    long sum = 0l;
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        sum += i;
        if ((((number + 1) * number) / 2) != sum)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}


public static int triangular(int number) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            count++;
        }

    }
    return count;
}

public static String number() {
    int count2 = 1;

    while ((triangle(count2) == true) && (triangular(count2) == 501)) {
        count2++;
    }
    return Integer.toString(count2);
}
```

Comment: `triangle` doesn't work; the sum will never reach the triangular number, because you sum from 0 to n-1 instead of from 1 to n, but if you know the closed form for calculating a triangular number, why are you also trying to calculate it by summing from 1 to n? Your function for counting the factors is highly inefficient, and in `number` you test every number; why not only test the triangular numbers? Also, you should check for over five hundred divisors, not five hundred and one divisors. Also, what Bucket said. :)

Comment: I think trying to solve this problem with a brute force is a bad idea. I bet there is some simple way to calculate the answer, even for some very high input number.

Comment: @Amongalen there may very well be, but most (if not all) problems in Project Euler require programming skills to solve.

Answer (score 3):

The conditions of your `while` loop cause it to exit early. You should invert the conditions so that you continue to iterate until those conditions are met. Also, the number you arrive at may have more than 501 factors, so you should allow for that possibility.

```
while ((triangle(count2) == false) || (triangular(count2) < 501)) {
    count2++;
}
```

As mentioned in the David Conrad's comment on the original post, you should sum your triangle numbers from `1` to `n` in `triangle()`, or just use the [explicit formula for calculating triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Your approach may also benefit from using a [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve).